# UPDATE: ERROR 1265 (01000): "Data truncated for column at row 1"

Tags: mysql, sql

table model (not good but i have to deal with..)

```
CREATE TABLE `vr_connection_param` (
   `connectionSize` enum('SMALL','MEDIUM','LARGE') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('OVP_BASIC','OVP_EXTENDED','TPASS') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `numberConnection` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`connectionSize`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

data recorded

```
select * from vr_connection_param;
+----------------+--------------+------------------+
| connectionSize | type         | numberConnection |
+----------------+--------------+------------------+
| SMALL          | OVP_BASIC    |                5 |
| SMALL          | OVP_EXTENDED |                5 |
| MEDIUM         | OVP_BASIC    |               10 |
| MEDIUM         | OVP_EXTENDED |               10 |
| LARGE          | OVP_BASIC    |               30 |
| LARGE          | OVP_EXTENDED |               30 |
+----------------+--------------+------------------+
```

try to update

```
update vr_connection_param
INNER JOIN
    (select distinct concat(`connectionSize`,`type`) from vr_connection_param where concat(`connectionSize`,`type`) like '%OVP_BASIC%') 
    AS TMP
SET type='OVPFE_EXPRESS';
```

error returned

```
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1
```

Comment: The value from your update statement is not in the enum form column type: `'OVP_BASIC','OVP_EXTENDED','TPASS'`. Why you will update it with an invalid value?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set the value `'OVPFE_EXPRESS'` in the `type` column which is an `enum` that doesn't contain that value. So the value is "truncated" (to `''`, apparently, according to my MySQL install).

---

It's also worth noting that the entire `INNER JOIN` part of your statement is a no-op, since you don't do anything with `TMP`. So you're just doing an `UPDATE` with (effectively) no `WHERE`.